# Why url rewriting not working?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I want to change my url from

`http://localhost/delhian/destinations_list.php?ref=monuments_in_delhi`

to

`http://localhost/delhian/destinations_list/monuments_in_delhi`

> I have written the following `htaccess` rules.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^destinations_list/([A-Za-z_]+)/?$      destinations_list.php?ref=$1
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here but this isn't working.

When I'm accessing the URL

`http://localhost/delhian/destinations_list/monuments_in_delhi`

It is showing me `Undefined index ref`.

**Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here, why it is not working and what is the meaning of this message `Undefined index ref`?**

Comment: In `destinations_list.php` can you do `var_dump($_GET);` and post the output? Your RewriteRule looks correct.

Comment: If you're not getting a 404 then it sounds like the rewrite is at least partially working...

Comment: `ref` is not defined because it is not mentiond in the url as GET method. But it is supposed to be, as I've written the rule in the .htaccess file. I don't know what I'm missing here.

Comment: The URL starts with `delhian/`. Unless you've used `rewritebase` e.g. `^delhian/destinations_list/([A-Za-z_]+)/?$ `

Comment: ^ ... unless `delhian` is a directory that actually exists, which contains both the `.htaccess` and `php` files.

Comment: `delhian` is actually a directory that contains both `.htaccess` and `php` files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add that, at the top of your htaccess, to disable MultiViews:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

The [Apache docs on mod_negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html), describes what the Multiviews Option does, when enabled:

> If the
>   server receives a request for /some/dir/foo and /some/dir/foo does not
>   exist, then the server reads the directory looking for all files named
>   foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those
>   files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it
>   would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then
>   chooses the best match to the client's requirements, and returns that
>   document.

Comment: Thank you, I'm glad I was able to help a little.